# How to fix "error while installing package installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10"

Tags: grub2, asus

I have an ASUS ROG laptop which used to run Windows 10, before I installed Ubuntu onto it. This is NOT a dual-boot laptop, but it having used to run windows might be a problem (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190110/grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-post-installation-script-subprocess-returned-error).) I was installing a graphics card driver update, when I got this error:
[error listed in question title. (please look at the image i beg of you)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biFAG.png)

I was also installing something from the snap store when I got the same error. Should I just reinstall Windows?